# Sort a numbers of strings in a cell array (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, sorting, cell-array

I have an input cell-array:

```
 Input-cell = { 'ACGBF','BAFCEDG','FECA','AGDFB', 'GFCEABD', 'EDFCBAG'}
```

There are 6 strings in the above cell-array. I used the following command to sort each of the strings into the alphabet sequences as follows:

```
 datasort = cellfun(@sort, randata, 'Uniformoutput', 0); % 6 strings were changed
```

Now, I would like to change just n=4 strings and keep the left m=2 strings as oringinal. How can I do that ? The expected output will be :

```
    Output-cell = { 'ACGBF','BAFCEDG','ACEF','ABDFG', 'ABCDEFG', 'ABCDEFG'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is simply pass-in the the part of the array you want to sort into your `cellfun`, and concatenate the rest, like so:

```
randata = { 'ACGBF','BAFCEDG','FECA','AGDFB', 'GFCEABD', 'EDFCBAG'};
n=4; 
datasort = [randata(1:end-n) cellfun(@sort,randata(end-n+1:end),'Uniformoutput',0)];

assert(isequal({ 'ACGBF','BAFCEDG','ACEF','ABDFG', 'ABCDEFG', 'ABCDEFG'},datasort));
```